# How to check device is rooted or not in ionic 2 typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular2-forms

I am developing a mobile app using ionic2. I need to check if android device is rooted. I did google and found the [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-root-detection) plugin `cordova-plugin-root-detection` but it does not work for me.

I added this plugin in my project using following command as explain in above link

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/trykovyura/cordova-plugin-root-detection.git`

after adding this plugin i tried to import it but it does not import, saying no module present. I did force quit my project and ran `npm insatll` and opened my project again but error still present.

```
rootDetection.isDeviceRooted(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Calling this does not work as module is not present.

Any reference of plugin or any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Did you put your code in a platform.ready() statement?

Comment: @JoeriShoeby yes i added code in platform.ready() statement

Comment: Are you getting errors during compile or run-time?

Comment: i am getting error during run time

Comment: Please provide full error message.

Answer (score 0):

Skip importing the plugin via Typescript and access it directly via the `window` global object.

```
 (<any>window).plugins.rootDetection.isDeviceRooted(successCB, errorCB)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer i tried it too..but same error saying module not found.